# python sorted function is not performing numeric sort as expected

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following code:

```
dict1={'1':'Ajay','1201':'Badol','102':'Cynthia','2':'Ravi','201':'John'}
for key,val in sorted(dict1.items()):
    print (key,val)
```

The Output I got:

```
('1', 'Ajay')
('102', 'Cynthia')
('1201', 'Badol')
('2', 'Ravi')
('201', 'John')
```

I was expecting:

```
('1', 'Ajay')
('2', 'Ravi')
('102', 'Cynthia')
('201', 'John')
('1201', 'Badol')
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: `for key,val in sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sorted as string, char by char. You need to convert it to integer in order to be sorted as numbers.

```
for key,val in sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])):
    print (key,val)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do, convert the key to int:

```
dict(sorted({int(k):v for k,v in dict1.items()}.items()))

{1: 'Ajay', 2: 'Ravi', 102: 'Cynthia', 201: 'John', 1201: 'Badol'}
```

**Explanation:**

1.`{int(k):v for k,v in dict1.items()}`: converts each key to int 
2. `sorted({int(k):v for k,v in dict1.items()}.items())`: calls the sorted function on the dictionary based on its keys. 
3. `dict`: sorted function above returns a list of tuples, hence we need to dict it again.

Answer (score 1):

Since your keys are strings you get "string" order.
You can provide your own key like this:

```
>>> for key in sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[0])):
...   print(key, val)
...
('1', 'Ajay') John
('2', 'Ravi') John
('102', 'Cynthia') John
('201', 'John') John
('1201', 'Badol') John
```

This treats the leys as numbers, giving what I think you want.